# In a forge web app, trying to get the unit's old short name from the new Revit 2021 units

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am developing a web application (using javascript) which uses forge viewer API.

In the application I display values of certain properties to the user.

I use Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.getProperties to get the properties and from there find he specific property I want.
I believe I get an object of type PropertyResult (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/PropertyResult/) for this example will assign it to "prop".

Then I display the property value with the unit by (assuming I know it is a number and has units):

```
var res = prop.displayValue.toFixed(2) + " " + prop.units;
```

This worked as we wanted when used on models from revit 2019 or 2020.
Showing for example:
"102.79 m^2"

However in model from revit2021 it will show:
"335.59 autodesk.unit.unit:squareMeters-1.0.1"

**I realize this happened because of the unit change in RevitAPI for 2021, however I have been trying to find a JS method to get the user friendly name from the new Autodesk unit type and wasn't able to find one.**
Will appreciate if anyone can direct me to that method or offer an alternative solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem that we've discovered recently. Unfortunately, there's no official workaround, and so if you need to compose measurements with units, for now you would have to map the Revit 2021 unit IDs to their display variants, e.g., mapping `autodesk.unit.unit:squareMeters-1.0.1` to `m^2`.

Please stay tuned to the Model Derivative service [changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/change_history/changelog).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Hoping you will solve this soon because I don't want to map every possible unit (and future units) myself.

Comment: I totally understand. Please note that we're now tracking this issue internally under the ID "DERI-6918" that you can use for future reference.