# Ho to Getting the model object properties in the right display units

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Do we have any way to convert from `autodesk.unit.unit:millimeters-1.0.1` to symbol `mm` without javascript library.

My problem is i'm wrting library in c# and python, and I want to show symbol unit of properties from model.

I saw this post but still same issue :

[Forge Viewer: How to use Units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352301/forge-viewer-how-to-use-units)

[In a forge web app, trying to get the unit's old short name from the new Revit 2021 units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492335/in-a-forge-web-app-trying-to-get-the-units-old-short-name-from-the-new-revit-2)

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Btw, where are you getting the properties from? Because e.g. the Model Derivative API returns the properties with the display units (caret instead of superscript though), e.g. "Area": "74.221 m^2"

Comment: Hi @Adam, I just try to explore access from database information.

Comment: From what database? I'm just trying to understand the exact workflow

Comment: Hi @Adam Nagy, I just want move data from magic sql to Unity 3D, I want all properties value have unit symbol, this is open source I tried to reference to achive : https://github.com/Piro-CIE/UnityForgeImporter. If you know any way can do better, please let's me know. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

We're looking into a generic solution, but in the meantime, you could come up with some code based on the `forgeUnitToSymbol()` function from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js

[image]

You could also store the contents of `FORGE_UNITS` used in that function. Based on some code comments it sounds like that content does not change often.